iOS getting context for view controller `isMovingFromParent`
Is there a way to identify how the popping of view controller from navigation controller is triggered? For example, with an edge swipe / pressing of the back button on the navigation bar / pressing of the tab bar item on the bottom bar?
I know that we can use isMovingFromParent in viewWillDisppear() like this but it doesn't explain the context for trigger.
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if isMovingFromParent {
      // view controller is popping.
    }
}

